# Tabulator Left-Align Headers

Tags: tabulator

In Tabulator, is it possible to generated a table that has Headers Left-Aligned? See screenshot for example:

[image: Table Example]

Comment: Most likely... What have you tried? Also tag question accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible i'm afraid, Tabulator currently only supports vertical columns

Comment: Could you provide a source or explanation for this statement?

Comment: There isn't any source example for this, it simply isn't a feature built into Tabulator at the moment, it only supports vertical columns

Comment: Okay, I didn't find anything in the documentation either. Your knowlegde and experience of the API can be seen as the source for this information, so looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks ggradnig, I'm the chap that developed Tabulator :D

Comment: Haha, that makes sense ;D